# Geowebcache "seed" doesn't seem to work

Tags: tiles, geowebcache

I'm using Geowebcache seed command (via web interface at `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/workspace:layerName`) and it looks like everything runs smoothly but actually no tiles are saved, at least where I'd expect them to be saved `(/data_dir/gwc)`.

I have GeoServer installed on top of Tomcat 7 as WAR. I also checked the logs (enabling `GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER` mode) and it doesn't give any errors. Actually if enabling `VERBOSE` logging mode I also get something like...

```
...    
2014-07-07 09:38:08,766 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2014-07-07 09:38:08,771 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2014-07-07 09:38:08,772 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2014-07-07 09:38:08,776 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2014-07-07 09:38:08,777 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-1 completed (re)seeding layer workspace:layerName after 448 tiles and 45 seconds.
...
```

...and it look like everything went fine. But in the end I have no tiles.

By the way, the tiles I'm trying to save to EPSG:900913 projection coming from EPSG:3045 PostGIS store (already done this operation successfully on another VM having GeoServer installed on top of Tomcat6 via `apt-get` instead than via WAR).

Any suggestion on how to inspect/solve the issue?

**Update:**

Following @EvilGenius advice I was able to find the missing tiles (in fact they quite strangely were served by the Geowebcache to the frontend) in `/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/geowebcache/workspace_layerName`.

Now the question becomes: how comes they are not copied/moved to the final location (`data_dir/gwc` folder)? again, how can I inspect that?

Comment: Have you checked all temporary folders that it could be in? I know that running Geoserver on Windows 7 and Tomcat 7 will put the cache in C:\Windows\Temp.

Comment: @EvilGenius: I checked in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data`, which is where the app is installed. The very strange thing is that my frontend app seems to be hitting cached layers (`geowebcache-cache-result: HIT`) and I can't figure out where they are stored.

Comment: It will depend on your distribution, but it probably wouldn't hurt to take a look in /tmp

Comment: @EvilGenius: oh my... there they are `/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/geowebcache/workspace_layerName`... How comes they're not moved in the `gwc` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/config.html#changing-the-cache-directory), you should be able to change the cache directory by setting the `GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR` parameter in GeoServer's web.xml file:

> To set a different directory, stop GeoServer (if it is running) and add the following code to your GeoServer web.xml file (located in the WEB-INF directory):
>
> ```
>  <context-param>
>       <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
>       <param-value>C:\temp</param-value>
>   </context-param>
> ```
>
> Change the path inside  to the desired cache path (such as C:\temp or /tmp). Restart GeoServer when done.

Note, the documentation *does* say that the default location should be within the data directory, which is incorrect.

Comment: Actually there's a page in the docs which explains it: http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/storage.html